# Controller doesn't equal to model name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I've model called BlogPost and controller called BlogPostsController that has all basic CRUD methods for BlogPost.

I'm trying to understand how I can route users to have URL like `/blog/post-name` instead of `/blog_posts/post-name` and "disable" in general URL `/blog_posts`. Should I rename my controller or should I change routes (and how)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your routes and add the `:as` option to your blog post resource route

```
map.resources :blog_posts, :as => 'blogs'
```

Comment: I think he wants `/blog`, so :as => 'blog' -- although the plural form is more conventional Rails...

Comment: @zetetic; yeah, I thought about that too, maybe 'posts' is a better resource name

Comment: I needed "/blog/posts" :) So I created namespace in routes: map.namespace :blog do |blog|, and inside blog.resources :posts, :controller => 'blog_posts' do |blog_posts| ...